# Django PrimaryKeyRelatedField queryset when allow_null=True

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to both Python and Django and I'm having issues with a nullable Foreign Key relation. I found similar issues to this one, but none of them seemed to be covering my use case.

I'm using Django 1.8.17, and DRF 3.1.0

I have the following classes in Django (I've simplified them out to just the relevant fields since I can't easily copy/paste my code here):

```
class Rationale(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Alert(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rationale = models.ForeignKey(Rationale, null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class AlertHistory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    alert =  = models.ForeignKey(Alert)
    rationale = models.ForeignKey(Rationale, null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class AlertHistoryListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = AlertHistory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlertHistorySerializer
    pagination_class = DefaultPagination

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = AlertHistoryFilterSet
    filter_fields = ['alert']
    ordering_fields = filter_fields        

class AlertHistoryFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = AlertHistory
        fields = ['alert']
```

The idea here is to capture changes to the alert in the history table. A user can update the priority or the Rationale.

The Rationale table is look-up that is pre-populated with a JSON fixture. A user can select a rationale to give the reason why the alert is open. Rationale is optional though, and therefore nullable.

However I get an error when I try to set the Rationale to None:

{'rationale': [u'Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received unicode.']}

So searching around led me to: the PrimaryKeyRelatedField: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

I then updated my AlertHistory serializer:

```
class AlertHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rationale = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AlertHistory
```

This fixed my first issue, but led to problems in the test where I'm updating the Rationale. By marking it read_only, I unsurprisingly cannot update that field.

The documentation says I need to specify either read_only=True or the queryset. However it doesn't provide an example of how to do that, and I can't figure it out or find any examples anywhere.

I need to cover both of the following cases:

data = {'alert' : 1, 'priority' : 2, rationale: 1 } to set the rationale to the foreign key for Rationale 1.

And:

data = {'alert' : 1, 'priority' : 2, rationale: None } if a user wants to set the rationale to null. This use-case is more likely when they are simply updating the priority without selecting a rationale.

So I tried defining my queryset to the "all"

```
rationale = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Rationale.objects.all(), allow_null=True)
```

but this causes all my tests where rationale is None to give the original exception:

{'rationale': [u'Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received unicode.']}, even though I now have allow_null set to True.

I then tried defining:

```
rationale = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Rationale.objects.get(pk=rationale), allow_null=True)
```

but it doesn't know what rationale is.

I also tried:

```
rationale = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='rationale', allow_null=True)
```

but that leads me to the error:

AssertionError: Relational field must provide a 'queryset' argument, or set read_only=`True`.

How do I properly define my queryset?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this serializer to get data from the objects as well as update the data, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. We need to be able to query the history table so we can show the changes over time. So a get at /alerts/history will return contents of the table, while a post to /alerts/history will let them change the values.

Comment: it is better to separate serializer fields - one for listing and retrieving with `read_only=True`, and another for creating and updating with `allow_null=True`
like 
`rationale = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset= Rationale.objects.all(), write_only=True, allow_null=True)` and `rationale = RationaleSerializer(read_only=True)`, for writing and reading respectively.
```

Answer (score 0):

use this serializer:

```
class AlertHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AlertHistory
```

model:

```
class AlertHistory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    alert =  = models.ForeignKey(Alert)
    rationale = models.ForeignKey(Rationale, null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

sample json for creating alert history object:

```
{
    "alert": 1,
    "rationale": null,
    "priority": 2
}
```

if you want to set rationale as null send `null` in json

PS: make sure your DB schema is updated and all the migrations have been applied.

Comment: So it's possible some (all?) of my issues are a Dict->JSON conversion issue. I'm using DRF's APIClient class to do my testing. 

data = data = {'alert' : 1, 'priority' : 2, rationale: None }

APIClient().post('alerts/history', data)

Maybe it's not converting data from None to null properly?

Comment: probably yes if you are sending `null` as `None`. checkout the correct json formatting. Did the above solution solve your issue?

Comment: No. I got errors when I tried setting fields = '__all__' in the serializer.

Comment: I will edit my answer. actually `'__all__'` is for the latest DRF version.

Comment: So what you're suggesting is exactly what I had that was leading to my original error. It's entirely possibly this is simply a test issue though. I have no idea how APIClient is converting my dictionary, but I tried json.dumps(data) and it's converting my None to a null, so I'm not sure that's the problem. For now I'm getting around the issue by only adding rationale to data when it's not None, but that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: can you post your view too. Because I am 100% sure the above serializer and model classes are correct. Perhaps your testing code has a bug.

Comment: I added the View class, and my Filter class for good measure. Sorry it takes me a bit since I have to rewrite everything by hand.

Comment: Your view code is correct too. It is a generic view which works correctly. I am using the same view to set the field as null. Perhaps it is a testing issue. Because the error clearly says it is getting a unicode string.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the input. For now I'll go with "test error" and see what happens when the UI guy does his integration.